# How can I get the IP of a client device connected through terminal services?

Tags: asp.net, terminal-services

## Problem

I need to get the client IP of a user connected through RDP/TS from an ASP site.

## Sample data

- The server hosting the site is at 10.1.0.1.
- The user's machine is connected to a terminal server whose IP is 10.2.0.1.
- The user is at a physical client whose IP is 10.3.0.1.

## Attempted solutions

I have tried pulling the data from headers.

- `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]` 10.2.0.1
- `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` [blank]
- `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` 10.2.0.1
- `Request.UserHostAddress` 10.2.0.1

I also tried these methods.

```
public static string getIP()
{
  string ips = string.Empty;
  string hostName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();
  IPAddress[] ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);
  foreach (IPAddress ipAddress in ipAddresses)
  {
    ips += ipAddress + "<br />";
  }
  return ips;
}
```

Returns 10.2.0.1.

```
public static string GetIPAddress()
{
  string ipAddress = "";
  string Hostname = Environment.MachineName;
  IPHostEntry Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Hostname);
  foreach (IPAddress IP in Host.AddressList)
  {
    if (IP.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
      ipAddress= Convert.ToString(IP);
    }
  }
  return ipAddress;
}
```

Returns 10.1.0.1.

## Question

Is it possible to get 10.3.0.1 returned since there is an extra hop from the user's physical client through the TS to the web server? Is this possible with another language--e.g., PHP?

Comment: From your application's perspective the remote client IS the terminal server so all of the methods to get the client address / hostname from your app will yield the terminal server's address / hostname.  There may be something lower level that can be done, but I don't think there is so I'm just commenting instead of answering.

Comment: You could check the client's IP on the web server, and if it matches your terminal server's IP, you could query the Remote Desktop Services API on the terminal server for the client's real IP. Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it's probably the closest you can get.